# how i print an array on flutter working with firebase?

Tags: arrays, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

First, thank your help.

I have the collection notes, with different documents and in them there is the field called description which is an array. In it there are different string which is what I want to print.

I know I have it mapped as a string, but nowhere do I see how to retrieve that data as if it were an array.

If you want to see the complete code you have it on my github, the project is called notas.

https://github.com/santiseijas/notas

I hope that I have explained well and I hope you can help me. Thank you very much for taking this time with me.

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>>#9eb25):
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> file:///C:/Users/seija/OneDrive/Escritorio/flutter/notas/lib/main.dart:72:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      new Notas.fromMap (package:notas/firebase/model.dart:12:21)
#1      new Notas.fromSnapshot (package:notas/firebase/model.dart:16:14)
#2      _MyHomePageState._buildItem (package:notas/main.dart:116:25)
#3      _MyHomePageState._buildList.<anonymous closure> (package:notas/main.dart:111:40)
#4      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:417:29)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Notas {
  final String titulo;
  final String descripcion;
  bool check;
  final DocumentReference reference;

  Notas.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
      : assert(map['titulo'] != null),
        titulo = map['titulo'],
        descripcion = map['descripcion'],
        check = map['check'];

  Notas.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);

  @override
  String toString() => titulo;
}
```

[image: firebase]

Answer (score 0):

```
 Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ...widget.snapshot.data.documents[widget.i].data['reportfiles']
              .map((values) {
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    values['name'],
                  ),
                ),
                Divider(),
              ],
            );
          }).toList()
        ],
      ),
```